# How do I make a Hapi plugin work only with a specific domain or subdomain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, subdomain, url-routing, hapi.js

I have the following inside my Hapijs project:

API plugin
Frontend plugin

Then I have a server folder which houses my main index.js file, where the Hapi server is initiated. I link everything together in my server folder with the Glue plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/glue

The problem I'm having is I want to use a subdomain for my api, for example api.locahost:8000 (api.domain.com). However, it seems no matter what type of subdomain I type in, I'm able to access my site.

Also, it's like random.localhost:8000 forwards to locahost:8000 and I can still access all of my website's pages.

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

const Dotenv = require('dotenv');
Dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env` });
const Glue = require('glue');

const manifest = {
    server: {
        port: process.env.PORT,
        host: process.env.HOST
    },
    register: {
        plugins: [
            {
                plugin: '~/api',
                options: {
                    routes: {
                        vhost: process.env.SUBDOMAIN //api.localhost
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                plugin: '~/lib'
            }
        ],
        options: {
        }
    }
};

const options = {
    relativeTo: __dirname
};

const startServer = async function () {

    try {
        const server = await Glue.compose(manifest, options);
        await server.start();
        await console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

startServer();
```

If you're wondering what "lib" is, that's my frontend directory name. If you look in the api plugin options, you can see where I've added my subdomain.

How can I make it so my frontend plugin uses only localhost:8000 and my API plugin uses only api.localhost:8000? Do they need to be two separate servers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible, but you can use lifecycle methods to access current path and domain and then you can insert a some kind of logic to your code to handle current domain.

For example, change lifecycle based on your needs before or after in the order.

```
exports.plugin = {    
    register: async function (server, options) {
        server.ext('onPreHandler', async (request, h) => {
            if(request.info.host !== 'YOUR_DOMAIN') return h.continue;
            // you can check request.path also

            // rest of the code...


            return h.continue;
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm going to read up on server.ext. This answer led me to my solution.